# How to exclude a specific file of a dependency in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The following code in a build.gradle file is for the testing only:

```
implementation('com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android') {
    exclude group: "com.google.guava"
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```

Android Studio reports the following error:

> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]
> on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.guava',
> name='guava', version='30.1.1-android', configuration='default'} of
> type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

How can I exclude a specific file of a dependency?

Comment: I think you have to use `exclude group: xxx` or `exclude module: yyy`, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-

Comment: @j.holetzeck Thank you for the tip. I cannot figure out how to use exclude group to exclude a file. The file I want to exclude is values.xml.